# Can a Windows 7 Home Premium 32bit retail be installed on new PC as 64bit OS?

Tags: windows-7, installation, 64-bit

Story: About four years ago, I bought a Windows 7 Home Premium and installed the 32 bit version due to compatibility issues with some applications that I use at that moment.

Now I have installed Android Studio and need more RAM so I'm thinking in to install the 64 bit version included in the Box on a new PC. Of course, I will no longer use the old PC; the idea is to have only one PC and sell the old PC as only hardware.

As far I read after doing some research is valid to install a Retail version on a new PC but only one PC can have the same Product Key but I don't know if I can change the OS version from 32 bit to 64 bit to handle more than 4 GB of RAM.

Answer (score 2):

From what you have said this shouldn't be a problem. Microsoft only cares about the activation of the OS not the architecture. However make sure of a few things first.

1. Make sure to wipe the drive of the old PC.
2. Make sure that you backup the data from your old PC.
3. If you have issues activating call MS and explain the situation.
4. Some of your applications may or may not be compatible with 64 bit architecture check with the applications developer for compatibility.

Other than that you shouldn't have any problems. Good luck!

Comment: Why you are mentioning the point number one? It's to avoid that the new user use the Product Key? If is for that, don't worry I will not sell the entire PC with the disk included; I just sell the motherboard, CPU and RAM modules I will keep the rest.

Comment: I mention it mainly so that if someone else comes along and wants to do something similar they don't give away their product key.